# Replacing too many if statements in bash

Tags: linux, bash, service, sh, rhel

I have written a bash script which works as follows

```
1) Check for status of service1. If it is not started then check for status of service2. If service2 is not started then display error.
2) If service1 is started then check for log file of service1 and grep for `starting`. If it matches then success
3) If service2 is started then check for log file of service1 and grep for `starting`. If it matches then success
```

My bash script looks as below but it has too many if statements. I am trying to figure out to reduce these many if statements

```
#!/bin/bash
service service1 status | grep "good" > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    service service2 status | grep "good" > /dev/null
    if [$? -ne 0];then
        var1="service1 is down"
        echo "$var1"
    else
        cat /dir/log2 | grep "abc" > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
            var2="exception"
            echo "$var2"
        fi
    fi
else
    cat /dir/log1 | grep "abc" > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
        var3="exception"
        echo "$var3"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't see a  problem here.. As if-else implements branching, i feel this is an efficient way to do it . `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **case** statement in bash to avoid multiple level if-else statements.

Following [blog](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement) might help you regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the exact logic you're trying to test -- the description doesn't quite match the code below. I suspect part of the problem is that doing negative tests (i.e. if something *wasn't* found, then...) can be confusing. So for example, the description says "If [Starting] matches then success", but the code does "If abc *does not* match then varN=exception". Also, it checks log1 if service2 is running, and checks log2 if service1 is running. I'd recommend switching to positive tests (i.e. if something *was* found, then...), and adding comments to keep track of what code runs under what conditions.

There are also some simplifications to the tests themselves. `somecommand; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` (a negative test -- it runs if the command failed) can be replaced by `if ! somecommand; then` (or `if somecommand; then` for the positive test version). Also, `grep something >/dev/null` can be replaced by `grep -q something` (with the advantage that it doesn't scan the entire file, it stops at the first match), and `cat somefile | grep something` can be replaced by `grep something somefile` (saving a process and making it more efficient).

Switching the tests to positive form and making the simplifications above, and also making what I think are the necessary corrections gives this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if service service1 status | grep -q "good"; then
    # This section executes if service1 is "good"
    if grep -q "abc" /dir/log1 2>/dev/null; then
        # service1 is "good" and /dir/log1 contains "abc"
        # Should there be something executable here? If not, add "!"
        # after the "if", and swap the "else" section here
        : success
    else
        # service1 is "good" and /dir/log1 does not contain "abc"
        # Is this where the "exception" stuff actually belongs?
        var3="exception"
        echo "$var3"
    fi

elif service service2 status | grep "good"; then
    # This section executes if service1 is not "good", but service2 is
    if grep -q "abc" /dir/log2 2>/dev/null; then
        # service2 is "good" and /dir/log2 contains "abc"
        : success
    else
        # service1 is "good" and /dir/log2 does not contain "abc"
        # Again, is this where the "exception" stuff actually belongs?
       var2="exception"
        echo "$var2"
    fi

else
    # Neither service1 nor service2 is "good"
    var1="service1 is down"
    echo "$var1"

fi
```